# The best way to install and keep Mumble 1.2.4 up-to-date on Debian Wheezy

Tags: package-management, debian-wheezy, mumble

I'd like to install the voice-chat client utility [Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) in its latest stable version 1.2.4 on my Debian Wheezy (7.3, stable) desktop system. The official repositories only have 1.2.3 packages available and the [Mumble Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~slicer/+archive/ppa) packages (which have the correct version) seem to have dependencies which are not available in Debian.

Still I'd like to install Mumble and also want to keep it up-to-date for security and bug-fixing reasons. What is the best way to achieve this? Manually visiting their website every now and then and building it manually when a new version is released appears to be a very maintenance intensive approach which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is to download the sources of the build dependencies (warning, this is more work that you should), install them on your own, copy the `debian/` directory from the official package and build it yourself. But then there are reasons [why this is not possible](http://packages.qa.debian.org/m/mumble.html):

- The package is currently ongoing 3 transitions which are boost1.54, protobuf and auto-libunwind.
- It depends of zeroc-ice which is not build currently in testing, but those problems are for other architectures, and probably is what it's stopping the package from installing.

I only see problems wanting to upgrade mumble. **If you have security concerns about the package afraid not, those are already fixed**. Now if you want the latest just to have the latest, Debian stable is not for you and you might feel more comfortable with Testing/Sid instead.